# Upload and Save an excel file with BottlePy

Tags: python-3.x, bottle

I am creating an application using Bottle framework. I need a feature to upload an Excel file. 
I am using the following for file upload.
http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#post-form-data-and-file-uploads

On the server side I am getting the file data as binary content. I want to save it in a temporary folder as an Excel file.

I am new to Python and Bottle. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Chirdeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `request.files.data` object contains the data about your excel file. So  you only need to create a temporary folder and save it inside. This can be done using [the tempfile module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html)

```
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix=".xlsx")
f.write(request.files.data.file.read())
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get simple file writing code like yours to work, So I used the tempfile module. Looking at your code, I would have assumed it would write to the directory where the python file is, if the code is working. Try using the code below, if you don't pass arguments to dir, it will create a file in the current directory.

```
def save_as_temp_file(data):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(dir=settings.TEMP_PATH,
            delete=False,
            suffix=".xlsx") as f:
        f.write(data.file.read())
        return f.name
```